# Ledger or chaincode state?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm running a HLF network with 4 peers, each from a different organisation, one kafka orderer and a zookeeper service.
My network seems to be running fine, with one exception: I can invoke chaincode but the state updates do not seem to be recorded by anyone  other than the peer invoking the chaincode. In other words, if I update the state with some chaincode from peer A, querying the state with some chaincode from peer B will return "null", but the same query (exact same code) from the chaincode ran by peer A will return the state correctly.

Is this normal? I assumed the sate of the ledger was independent of the chaincode peers run, or is the state really chaincode state?

Edit: I've tested installing the chaincode of peer A on peer B, and once that's done it can query the state as required. As I was using different chaincodes to control who could invoke which functions, is there a way to limit which functions can be invoked within chaincode?

Answer (score 0):

Data written with chaincodes installed are specific to that chaincode only.
If you want to access chaincodedata-A from chaincode B, you have to internally invoke chaincode A from within chaincode B (provided, chaincode A and B are belonging to the same channel).

How do you want to restrict chaincode invocation? If it is on a user/role level basis, you can check by the attributes of the user inside the chaincode and make decisions accordingly. (However this is a v1.1 feature)

Ref : https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5346

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Internally invoking chaincode A from chaincode B to query should be ok. Does this mean the PutState function writes data to the chaincode state only then? My goal with regards to resitricting chaincode invocation is that for exmaple I'd like some peers to be able to execute transactions and others to only obtain the log of transactions, hence one set of peers has the chaincode to execute a transaction (including PutState) and another has chaincode to return the state of the ledger with GetStateByRange.